# how to create a tagging system with nodejs for website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, tagging

I'm creating a CMS blog with `Node js` but i failed to create a tagging system for posts, i want this tagging system to be connected to MongoDB so i can do CRUD operation on every tag and search for posts According to their tags.

i created these codes for front end :

```
//enter something in textbox and press enter....
var tags = [];
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').on('click', 'span.cross', function () {
        var removedItem = $(this).parent().contents(':not(span)').text();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        tags = $.grep(tags, function (value) {
            return value != removedItem;
        });
    });

    $("#textBox").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag' >" + this.value + '<span class="cross">X</span>' + "</a>");

            tags.push(this.value);
            this.value = "";
        }
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/pDFnG/

my problem starts from here that i don't know the nature of post tags so i can't write any code for that,what do you recommend me to do?

Comment: As you mentioned in a comment to my answer, if SEO is part of the problem you should add it to your question, just so answers can be more relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to save a tags element to each post document as an array and simply store a list of strings in it.
Then the user can specify the tags they want and the code doesn't need to know what they are, it just stores them.

Mongo can then give you a distinct list of all tags:

```
db.posts.distinct('tags')
```

And search for any posts that contain a specific tag or a list of tags:

```
db.posts.find({tags: {$in: ['tag1', tag2', 'tag3']}})
```

That is CLI commands I wrote there, they'll be slightly different if you're using Mongoose or similar.

Does that help?

Comment: `db.posts.distinct('tags')` this operation is super memory consuming operation. With large set of data, it will fail.

Comment: Ok.but,How can search engines see tags, to increase seo?

Comment: The tags will be passed back as part of the page content, same as the rest of the content that gets crawled. How best to do depends on the current state of SEO (I'm far from an expert in that area). Hopefully the tags picked will actually tie into the content and be mentioned there, in the title and several times in the main text.

Comment: @Steve How should I keep data as a part of pages content? As a tag or JavaScript code or...?

Comment: Can you please introduce me to some reference or documents?

Comment: @sina, I'm not an expert in SEO, it isn't a topic that interests me, so I can't point you to any good advise. Sorry.

Comment: SOLVED. Thanks to @Steve, i asked more about saving data in document for SEO increment and i learned that we have to keep this kind of data into meta tags, so we must render mea tags and add data into them. the source of this answer is from here : https://www.wordstream.com/meta-tags